# how to optimize laravel jobs inside loop

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

There is a function that is inside the job (queue) . and I dispatch that queue. Inside for each loop.

```
public function autoConsignmentChargeCalculate($consignments, $user_id, $notify)
    {
        $i = 1;
        $total_consignments = $consignments->count();


        $jobs = [];
        foreach ($consignments as  $consignment) {

            $jobs[] = new CalculateSingleConsignment($consignment, $total_consignments, $i, $user_id, $notify);
            $i++;
        }
        if (count($jobs) > 0) {
            Bus::chain($jobs)->onQueue('invoice')->dispatch();
        }
    }
```

The function inside the job is

```
public function calculateConsignmentOneByOne($consignment, $total_consignments, $current_iteration, $user_id, $notify)
    {

        if ($consignment->finalize == 0) {

            $type = 'Income';
            $customer = Customer::find($consignment->customer_id);
            $delivery_run_id = $consignment->delivery_run_id;
            if ($consignment->consignment_type == 'pickup' || $consignment->consignment_type == 'return') {
                $delivery_address_id = $consignment->pickup_address;
            } else {
                $delivery_address_id = $consignment->delivery_address;
            }
            $customer_id = $consignment->customer_id;
            $rate_zone = $consignment->rate_zone_id;
            if ($rate_zone == null) {
                $address_to_rate_zone_mapping = getRateZoneByAddressMapping($consignment, $type);

                if ($address_to_rate_zone_mapping != false) {
                    $rate_zone = 0;
                    $rate_zone = $address_to_rate_zone_mapping;
                } else {
                    $rate_zone =   $this->getRateZone($delivery_run_id, $delivery_address_id, $type);
                }
            }
            if (!empty($consignment->invoice)) {
                if ($consignment->invoice->status === 3) {
                    $error = 'Related Invoice is Approved,Now you Can not modify charges';
                    chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'invoice_approved', $error, $type);
                }
            }
            $productType = $consignment->product_type_id;
            if ($rate_zone === 'wrong_delivery_run') {
                $error = 'No Delivery Run is Assigned to this consignment';
                chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'wrong_delivery_run', $error, $type);
            } else if ($rate_zone === 'wrong_delivery_zone') {
                if ($consignment->consignment_type == 'pickup' || $consignment->consignment_type == 'return') {
                    $address_msg = 'Pickup address';
                } else {
                    $address_msg = 'Delivery address';
                }
                $error = 'Delivery Zone not found with current suburb and postcode given in ' . $address_msg;

                chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'wrong_delivery_zone', $error, $type);
            } else if (empty($productType)) {
                $error = 'Please Attach Product Type to Consignment';
                chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'product_type_error', $error, $type);
            } else if ($rate_zone === 'wrong_delivery_address') {
                $error = 'Delivery Address not Found , May be Deleted';
                chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'wrong_delivery_address', $error, $type);
            } else {
                $rate_charge = $this->getRateChargeByRateZoneAndCustomer($rate_zone, $type, $consignment, $customer);

                if ($rate_charge === 'rate_not_found') {
                    $error = 'Rate Card in Customer Charge with "' . RateZone::find($rate_zone)->name . '" Rate zone or Charge Type not found';
                    chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'rate_not_found', $error, $type);
                }
                if ($rate_charge === 'customer_not_found') {
                    $error = 'Customer Not Found, May be Deleted';
                    chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'customer_not_found', $error, $type);
                }
                if ($rate_charge === "invalid_carton_pallet") {
                    $error = 'No pallets or cartons given, check the consignment data has been loaded correctly.';
                    chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'invalid_carton_pallet', $error, $type);
                }
                if ($rate_charge === "invalid_invoice_value") {
                    $error = 'No invoice value given, check the consignment data has been loaded correctly.';
                    chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'invalid_invoice_value', $error, $type);
                }
                if ($rate_charge === "invalid_weight") {
                    $error = 'No Weight value given, check the consignment data has been loaded correctly.';
                    chargeError('Consignment', $consignment->id, 'invalid_weight', $error, $type);
                } else {


                    if ($type == 'Income') {
                        $rate_charge_array =   array('class' => null, 'type' => $type, 'description' => $this->chargeDescription, 'income' => $rate_charge, 'expense' => 0.00, 'rate_zone_id' => $rate_zone, 'customer_id' => $customer->id, 'apply_fuel_levy' => $this->fuelLevy, 'object_id' => $consignment->id, 'model' => 'Consignment', 'automatic' => 1);
                    } else {
                        $rate_charge_array = array('class' => null, 'type' => $type, 'description' => $this->chargeDescription, 'income' => 0.00, 'expense' => $rate_charge, 'rate_zone_id' => $rate_zone, 'customer_id' => $customer->id, 'apply_fuel_levy' => $this->fuelLevy, 'object_id' => $consignment->id, 'model' => 'Consignment', 'automatic' => 1);
                    }
                    if ($type == 'Income') {
                        $final_charges = $this->getAdhocChargeRate($consignment, 'Consignment');
                    }

                    $final_charges[] = $rate_charge_array;
                    $final_charges = collect($final_charges);

                    Charge::where('object_id', $consignment->id)->where('automatic', 1)->where('model', 'Consignment')->delete();
                    ChargeError::where('object_id', $consignment->id)->where('model', 'Consignment')->delete();

                    $this->storeAutoCalculatedConsignmentCharges($final_charges);
                    $this->calculateFuelLevyForConsignment($consignment->id);



                    //this will keep updating fuel levy with each consignment calculation
                    // if (InvoiceTotal::where('invoice_id', $consignment->invoice_id)->where('name', 'Fuel Levy')->exists()) {
                    //     $income = 0;
                    //     $expense = 0;
                    //     $total = InvoiceTotal::where('invoice_id', $consignment->invoice_id)->where('name', 'Fuel Levy')->first();
                    //     $income = (float)$total->income + (float)$consignment->charges()->sum('fuel_levy_value');
                    //     $expense += 0;
                    //     InvoiceTotal::where('invoice_id', $consignment->invoice_id)->where('name', 'Fuel Levy')->update(['income' => $income, 'expense' => $expense]);
                    //     $invoice = Invoice::find($consignment->invoice_id);


                    //     Invoice::where('id', $consignment->invoice_id)->update(['income' => $invoice->invoice_totals()->sum('income'), 'expense' => $invoice->invoice_totals()->sum('expense')]);
                    // }
                    Invoice::find($consignment->invoice_id)->update(['sum_up' => 0]);
                }
            }



            $last_consignment = Consignment::select('id', 'invoice_id')->where('invoice_id', $consignment->invoice_id)->where('finalize', 0)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
            $invoice_id = $consignment->invoice_id;

            //if its last consignment to calculate and notify is true
            if ($notify && $total_consignments == $current_iteration) {
                Notification_Helper::sendNotification($user_id, 'Invoice Calculation is Completed ', route('invoices.show', $consignment->invoice_id));
            }
            $upload_to_xero = 0;
            if (XeroCustomer::where('customer_id', $consignment->customer_id)->exists()) {
                if (XeroCustomer::where('customer_id', $consignment->customer_id)->first()->automatic_invoice_upload_xero == 1) {
                    $upload_to_xero = 1;
                }
            }

            if ($consignment->id == $last_consignment->id) {
                Invoice::find($invoice_id)->update(['calculation_complete' => 1]);
                $this->consignmentSumup($invoice_id);
            }


            //if its last consignment to calculate and has no charge error then
            //invoice will be uploaded to xero
            if ($consignment->id == $last_consignment->id) {
                //checking if error exists Related to current invoice
                $consignment_charge_exists = ChargeError::where('model', 'Consignment')->whereIn('object_id', function ($query) use ($invoice_id) {
                    $query->select('id')
                        ->from(with(new Consignment)->getTable())
                        ->where('invoice_id', $invoice_id);
                })->exists();

                $po_charge_exist = ChargeError::where('model', 'Purchase Order')->whereIn('object_id', function ($query) use ($invoice_id) {
                    $query->select('id')
                        ->from(with(new PurchaseOrder)->getTable())
                        ->where('invoice_id', $invoice_id);
                })->exists();

                $so_charge_exist = ChargeError::where('model', 'Sale Order')->whereIn('object_id', function ($query) use ($invoice_id) {
                    $query->select('id')
                        ->from(with(new SaleOrder)->getTable())
                        ->where('invoice_id', $invoice_id);
                })->exists();

                $sp_charge_exist = ChargeError::where('model', 'Storage Period')->whereIn('object_id', function ($query) use ($invoice_id) {
                    $query->select('id')
                        ->from(with(new StoragePeriod)->getTable())
                        ->where('invoice_id', $invoice_id);
                })->exists();
                if (!$consignment_charge_exists && !$po_charge_exist && !$so_charge_exist && !$sp_charge_exist && $upload_to_xero == 1 && $this->consignmentSumup($invoice_id)) {
                    UploadInvoiceToXero::dispatch($consignment->invoice_id)->onQueue('invoice')->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(2));
                    // CustomerController::uploadAutoInvoiceToXero($consignment->invoice_id, $xeroCredential, new CustomerSettingService);
                    Invoice::find($consignment->invoice_id)->update(['sum_up' => 1]);
                } else {
                    Invoice::find($consignment->invoice_id)->update(['sum_up' => 1, 'charge_error' => 1]);
                }
            } else {
                Invoice::find($consignment->invoice_id)->update(['sum_up' => 1, 'charge_error' => 1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is there are about 20,30 queries inside this function. and I have to dispatch this job about 25000 times. when it reaches 200 jobs. My aws DB CPU utilization reaches 100%.

Now I am looking for an optimal solution I can increase DB instance size but I think that is not a solution.

What is good practice I can use here?

Comment: Firstly, is it mandatory to process all the queued jobs simultaneously. Secondly, is there any way to minimize the no of DB queries you consume.

Comment: yes it is mendatory to run all jobs at once . because we generate weekly invoices.. and it has to complete overnight

Comment: When you have 200 SQL tasks actually _running_ at the same time, things will slow down.  This is because the queries are stumbling over each other.

Comment: If you would like help optimizing SQL, please provide the SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is quite fast at doing the "same" thing to lots of rows at the "same" time.

What you seem to have is code that does 20-30 small queries 25K times.

Consider doing 20-30 (maybe a few more than that) queries, each of which acts on 25K rows.  Then chuck all the queuing and don't worry about "simultaneously".

Comment: Your answers seems interesting but i didn't understand it completely. More explanation will be appriciated

Comment: @BilalArshad - Let's see some of the 20-30 queries.